# How to put list values in django's rest framework json response

Tags: python, json, django, rest, django-rest-framework

In one of my django projects I've set up the **django-rest-framework** in such a way so that it returns the following type of json response:

```
{
    "name": "John", 
    "last_name": "Smith", 
    "age": 35, 
    "dl_url": "[u'http://domain.com/file1', u'http://domain.com/file2']"
}
```

So far so good.

The problem is that I need to return the `dl_url` attribute as a *list* and not a *string* so that it becomes:

```
{
    "name": "John", 
    "last_name": "Smith", 
    "age": 35, 
    "dl_url": [u'http://domain.com/file1', u'http://domain.com/file2']
}
```

What's the best way to do that?

Please note that I am storing the links as a `models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)` instance in my `models.py`.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just convert it to a list using the serializer methods. In order to do so, use the [to_representation](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#removal-of-transform_field_name) method introduced in drf 3.0 (in previous versions it was called transform or smth similar).

`def to_representation(self, instance):
    ret = super(UserSerializer, self).to_representation(instance)
    ret['dl_url'] = ret['dl_url'].split(',')
    return ret`

Comment: Thank you. It works now. However please note that I had it working only after reading the example of this page http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/ which provides a nice example of how to put it under a serializer class which inherits from `serializers.ModelSerializer` instead of doing what was stated in the api documentation: http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/ the example of which only states how to inherit from `serializers.Field`.

Answer (score -1):

Try this :

old_response = {
    "name": "John", 
    "last_name": "Smith", 
    "age": 35, 
    "dl_url": "[u'http://domain.com/file1', u'http://domain.com/file2']"
}

new_response = old_response

new_response['dl_url'] = new_response['dl_url'][1:-1].split(',')

Comment: You have to go through the serializer. It's not as simple as 'casting' from one type to another...